# Issues with CSS Dynamic Div Tags adjusting to Static Div Tags

Tags: css, html, dynamic, static, tags

I've been having quite a few issues with dynamic div tags that take into account static div tags. Here's the 2 styles I'm currently using:

Dynamic Div tag:

```
div.Display {
width: 95%;
color: #333333;
margin-left: 360px;
background-color: #333333;
height: 100%;
margin-right: 0px;
float: left;
}
```

Static Div tag:

```
div.LoginBox {
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px #000000;
width: 350px;
height: 350px;
background-color: #F0F0F0;
border: 1px solid #DADADA;
clear: none;
float: left;
color: #000000;
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the dynamic div tag won't size properly. It's taking into account the margin left (360px), but it's also defaulting to the bottom of the LoginBox div tag (so it's like it's taking a top margin of 350px). Here's the actual application of the Div tag: http://ordwurkz.com/

And the HTML:

```
<body onload="FP_preloadImgs(/*url*/'images/hover/minimize.png',/*url*/'images/click/minimize.png')">

<div class="Page" id="Page">

<div class="LoginContainer" id="LoginContainer">
<div id="divLoginTitleBar" class="TitleBar">
    Login   
    <div id="divTitleButtonBox" class="TitleButtonBox">

        <img id="LoginMinimize" alt="Button Text" onmousedown="FP_swapImg(1,0,/*id*/'LoginMinimize',/*url*/'images/click/minimize.png')" onmouseout="FP_swapImg(0,0,/*id*/'LoginMinimize',/*url*/'images/minimize.png')" onmouseover="FP_swapImg(1,0,/*id*/'LoginMinimize',/*url*/'images/hover/minimize.png')" onmouseup="FP_swapImg(0,0,/*id*/'LoginMinimize',/*url*/'images/hover/minimize.png')" src="images\minimize.png"/><img id="LoginClose" alt="Button Text" onmousedown="FP_swapImg(1,0,/*id*/'LoginClose',/*url*/'images/click/close.png')" onmouseout="FP_swapImg(0,0,/*id*/'LoginClose',/*url*/'images/close.png')" onmouseover="FP_swapImg(1,0,/*id*/'LoginClose',/*url*/'images/hover/close.png')" onmouseup="FP_swapImg(0,0,/*id*/'LoginClose',/*url*/'images/hover/close.png')" src="images\close.png"/></div>
</div>

<div id="divLoginBox" class="LoginBox">
<div id="divLoginContent" class="LoginContent">

<img alt="System Image" src="images/loginsplash.png" />

<form method="post" action="processor\login_processor.do" id="frmLogin">    

    <table id="tblLoginContent" class="LoginContent">
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td>
            <input maxlength="50" name="txtUsrName" size="20" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td>
            <input maxlength="24" name="txtPassword" size="20" type="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="btnLogin" type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            <td><input name="btnReset" type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="PlatformVersion">V1.0.0.0</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="Display"></div>

</div>
<div class="Footer">Contact Us | Terms of Service</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The issue is it's not working how it should. I am using jquery so I'm wondering if it might be causing the issue. This is the actual site it's on: http://ordwurkz.com/

Comment: We need to know that you want it to do instead of what it's doing

Comment: It needs to take up the entire right side of the page. As you can see, it's, instead, only taking up until the bottom of the first Div tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you could put your .LoginBox inside of your .Display, then remove the margin-left on .Display so that .LoginBox just floats to the left of the content in .Display??  Hard to really say without seeing your HTML.